# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: tensorflow

I'm facing a trouble with tensorFlow. Executing the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import input_data

learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 25
batch_size = 100
display_step = 1

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

# tensorflow graph input
X = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784]) # mnist data image of shape 28 * 28 = 784
Y = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 10]) # 0-9 digits recognition = > 10 classes

# set model weights
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

# Our hypothesis
activation = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W),b)  # Softmax

# Cost function: cross entropy
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=activation, logits=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)  # Gradient Descen
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph
>   for ops that do not support gradients, between variables
>   ['Tensor("Variable/read:0", shape=(784, 10), dtype=float32)',
>   'Tensor("Variable_1/read:0", shape=(10,), dtype=float32)'] and loss
>   Tensor("Mean:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).

Comment: I solved this problem by change of args..
(labels=activation, logits=Y) → (labels=Y, logits=activation)

it was a logic problem. thanks

Answer (score 24):

This problem is caused by the following line: `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=activation, logits=Y)`

Based on [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) you should have

> labels: Each row labels[i] must be a valid probability distribution.
>
> logits: Unscaled log probabilities.

So logits suppose to be your hypothesis and thus equal to `activation` and valid probability distribution is `Y`. So just change it with `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y, logits=activation)`

Answer (score 20):

I ended up here because I had passed my input X data to my model, but not my expected outputs. I had:

```
model.fit(X, epochs=30)      # whoops!
```

I should have had:

```
model.fit(X, y, epochs=30)   # fixed!
```

Comment: This was my case too

Comment: What is the value of y? Where have you declared it? / From where have you got it?

Comment: `y` is an array that indicates the values the model should predict. It has one entry for each entry in `X`...

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've forgotten to add the compile layer to the model

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I solved it by reducing the learning rate from 0.01 to 0.0001 and training had start without errors. I used RMSprop as optimizer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35397857)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).